# How to install mysql, mysql workbench on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I am having problems trying to install mysql workbench. Says there is no mysqlclient installed, but I already have. and when you run mysql server also gives error. I am using mysql 5:16:17.
How do I uninstall mysql and install a version that can work with workbench?

Note: I will work with these mysql with RVM and ruby 1.8.7. These are already installed.
What should I do?

Comment: ... "also gives an error". And we need to guess what error it is and the one that has the correct one gets accepted?!

Answer (score 3):

Try, at this order:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Worked just fine for me!